# Ubuntu 16.04 freezing on adding pcie_aspm=force in grub file

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, battery, freeze

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 fresh. In order to reduce battery drain I added TLP and also edited a line in /etc/default/grub from

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"

And now my screen freezes in every two second.

I somehow undid the change in grub file but the issue still persists. Please help.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Before you spend much time trying to fix 16.04 are you aware it reaches end of standard support in less then 3 weeks? After that you will not get any updates or security patches and can not ask questions here about it. You may want to upgrade to 18.04 or better till 20.04 and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: Thanks David for suggestion.